# Is there any joke in this sentence?

Tags: jokes

Tej and Roman are getting launched into space with old suits:

> Roman: What we supposed to be doing with these old-ass suits that
> ain't been used since World War I?
>
> Tej: Oh, I'm sorry. **Astronauts "R" Us was closed for shopping
> today**. Listen, these suits are just like space suits. They both
> account for pressure differential.

Is there any joke in this sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a joke. In the US, there is a chain of toy stores called **Toys "R" Us**. Each store is very big. You can find almost any toy there that is currently being manufactured.

Tej is sarcastically pretending that a store exists called **Astronauts "R" Us.** Such a store would likewise sell every possible kind of space suit you could imagine. Unfortunately, this imaginary store is closed, so they cannot purchase the space suits they really want.

What he really means is something like this:

> Shut up and be satisfied that we have any suits at all.